# FadeIn react component using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

According to react documentation only way to animate is by using`ReactCSSTransitionGroup`. Is there anyway to do animation using only Javascript?
 Thanks.

Comment: You can perform simple animations like fadein with pure css. That's most simple way without extra code or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical way to do a fadeIn animation is:

- define a css-class that animates fadeIn in someway
- in `componentDidMount()`, add a `setState()` method that adds the faded-in class to your component
- your component will then re-render, with the new class. Applying any css animations that you have defined (in css of course)

PS: With simple javascript, you can only add animation when the component appears, or when it updates.
When your component leaves (so if you would want a fade-out animation), it is much, much harder to do that with javascript only.

Comment: Thanks, didn't wanted to css thing. now going to do that. thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found [this npm package](https://github.com/tejitak/react-state-animation) It has all the basic animation.

for fadeIn animation

```
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    this.state = {
     opacity: 0
    }
  // react state animation wrapper
  this._animate = new ReactStateAnimation(this)
}
componentDidMount () {
  this._fadeIn();
}

_fadeIn = () => {
   this._animate.linearIn('opacity', 0.9, 300);
};
```

pretty simple!